# How to disable / enable TeamViewer service on Linux and Windows?

Tags: services, teamviewer

This question is for purposes of disabling unnecessary running service in the background of program called TeamViewer.

Normally, the background service is running all the time.

I wish for it to be disabled from PowerShell Administrator prompt and re-enabled upon request / and similarly from Linux Terminal.

Preferrably by one simple command or defined function.

Note1: I need this both on Windows (10) and Linux (Mint 18).

Note2: I need CLI solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Linux (Terminal)

- Enabling:

  ```bash
  sudo teamviewer daemon enable
  ```
- Disabling:

  ```bash
  sudo teamviewer daemon disable
  ```

Your personal aliases would look exactly like that.

Just add them to your personal Bash aliases file:

> ```
> ~/.bash_aliases
> ```

- Enabling:

  ```bash
  alias tv-enable='sudo teamviewer daemon enable'
  ```
- Disabling:

  ```bash
  alias tv-disable='sudo teamviewer daemon disable'
  ```

---

### Windows (PowerShell)

- Enabling:

  ```powershell
  sc.exe config "TeamViewer" start= auto
  net start TeamViewer
  ```
- Disabling:

  ```powershell
  sc.exe config "TeamViewer" start= disabled
  net stop TeamViewer
  ```

Your personal aliases would look exactly like that.

Just add them to your personal PoweShell profile file:

> ```
> $PROFILE
> ```

- Enabling:

  ```powershell
  function tv-enable {
      sc.exe config "TeamViewer" start= auto
      net start TeamViewer
  }
  ```
- Disabling:

  ```powershell
  function tv-disable {
      sc.exe config "TeamViewer" start= disabled
      net stop TeamViewer
  }
  ```